# Issue with angular 2 ngControl's minlength errors validator

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following angular 2 form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="updateFirstName()" #firstNameForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="getCssClasses(formCtrl, formCtrl.firstName)">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   ngControl="firstName"
                   #firstName="ngForm"
                   required
                   minlength="2"
                   maxlength="35"
                   pattern_="FIRST_NAME_PATTERN"
                   [ngModel]="currentUserAccount?.firstName"
                   (ngModelChange)="currentUserAccount ? currentUserAccount.firstName = $event : null"
                   placeholder="{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.NEW_FIRST_NAME'| translate }}"
                   class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="firstName.valid">
            <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength" class="control-label">{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.MIN_LENGTH'| translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.SUBMIT'| translate}}</button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/useraccount']" class="btn btn-link pull-right text-right">{{'FORM_CANCEL' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

However it seems errors is null as I get the following error when I load the form in the browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minlength' of null
```

What I am getting wrong here?

Is the declarative use of minlength attribute in the template not sufficient?

Is there another way to declare the minlength validator than in a programmatic way i.e.

```
this.name = new Control('', Validators.minLength(4));
```

?

Comment: Maybe you need to use elvis operator like this *ngIf="firstName?.errors?.minlength"

Comment: Why not add it as an answer, then @balteo can accept it and the question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**I have faced the same problem, i.e. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'minlength' of null`. For me, the solution proposed by @yurzui solved the problem. I am adding it as an answer here (as suggested by @günter-zöchbauer), so that others (who may not read the comments) can easily find it.**

Problem:

The `minlength` property may be accessed, before `errors` is defined:

```
<div *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength">
    Too short
</div>
```

**Solution:**

Use the `?` operator to ensure that `errors` is defined, before accessing its `minglength` property:

```
<div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.minlength">
    Too short
</div>
```

**Alternative Solution:**

Wrap your div in another div that checks if `errors` is defined:

```
<div *ngIf="firstName.errors">
    <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.minlength">
        Too short
    </div> 
</div>
```

Note that both solutions assume that `firstName` is defined.

*PS: For anyone who needs it, the same applies to `errors.maxlength` as well!*

Comment: Love the idea of wrapper div. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

// In this way it is working for me

```
<div *ngIf="firstName?.errors?.minlength">

</div>
```

Comment: This adds nothing that is not already given in the [answer provided by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965787/10871073) nearly two years ago.